# Why space of Radon measures is a lattice?

Tags: functional-analysis, measure-theory

Why space of Radon measures is a lattice? In other words, why for every Radon measure $\varphi$ exist sup$(\varphi, 0)$?

Comment: Do you know the Hahn-Jordan decomposition of a measure?

Comment: What is your definition of a Radon measure?